# Splash with Privoxy/Tor do not work (localhost conflict?)

Tags: scrapy, tor, splash-screen, scrapy-splash, privoxy

Splash doesn't work with Privoxy/Tor. Although

- Privoxy/Tor works in the browser.
- Splash works with a normal proxy. `yield SplashRequest(url,
  self.parse_func, args={'wait': 2.5, 'proxy':
  'http://a_proxy_address:port', })`.
- Scrapy without Splash works via Privoxy. `yield
  scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_func, meta={'proxy':
  'http://127.0.0.1:8118'})`).

In a script Splash give error 502.

If try in browser open Splash page `localhost:8050`, it give errror page: 
`Privoxy was unable to socks5t-forward your request http://localhost:8050/ through localhost: SOCKS5 request failed`

/etc/privoxy/config:

```
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .
forward-socks4 / localhost:9050 .
forward-socks4a / localhost:9050 .
forward-socks5t / localhost:9050 .
```

I also tried to add in `/etc/privoxy/config` the following line, but it didn't help.

```
forward localhost  .
```

Comment: Are you running splash inside docker?

Comment: Yes, `sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using splash and passing it a localhost proxy. When splash tries to use `127.0.0.1:8118`, this refers to the splash container itself and there is nothing running there. So it fails.

Two possible solutions

**Run splash on host network**

```
sudo docker run --net host scrapinghub/splash
```

**Give proxy IP**

If you laptop/PC has a `192.168.0.101` IP from the router then use

```
yield SplashRequest(url,
self.parse_func, args={'wait': 2.5, 'proxy':
'http://192.168.0.101:8118', })
```

Comment: 1) Works, if also add `'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'` in a request. Thank you! But on this way don't works Tor with Splash in the browser on http://localhost:8050.

Comment: What proxy IP were you using for the `SplashRequest`?

Comment: I tried `'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'` and `'proxy': 'http://192.168.1.102:8118'` (IP of my PC),

Comment: What is issue you see?

Comment: If run without Splash `scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_func,  meta={'proxy': 'http://192.168.1.102:8118'})` error: `twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.` (But proxy works if set `'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'`.)

Comment: While `sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash` and  `SplashRequest(url, self.parse_func,args={'wait': 2.5,'proxy': 'http://192.168.1.102:8118',})` get error: 
`[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (502) <GET http://myip.ru via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None) 
[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <502 http://myip.ru>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`.

Comment: That is a timeout, TOR is a very slow proxy, you should increase the timeout for your requqest

Comment: On 1-way it works quickly. In both case Tor with Splash don't works in browser, so better use 1-way.  Again thank you.

Comment: Perhaps, I also will try [aquarium](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium), there is support of Tor for Splash.

Comment: @bl79 for what it worths, aquarium runs Tor - does something very similar to what you're asking. It does that by using docker-compose to link Splash and a container with tor proxy. Privoxy is not needed because Splash has native SOCKS5 proxy support.